# does "echo -m > /proc/sysrq-trigger" run in process context when it runs from script?

Tags: linux, magic-sysrq

we have a script which runs below sysrq command to get memory info in syslog and then script copies the syslog.

```
echo -m > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

From documentation I see that at the at kernel level "handle_sysrq" gets called which runs in the interrupt context but there are two ways `sysrq` is triggered right ?

1. one is keys combination on keyboard. And
2. another is by writing appropriate character to`/proc/sysrq-trigger` file.

Now we want to know if memory-info gets written to `syslog/dmesg` immediately before echo returns or it is `memory-info` is written after echo returns ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your underlying question is how to make sure that the memory information has been logged by the time you copy the system log...

I haven't checked the code but I think it's all asynchronous. If you want to serialise operations you can do so by writing to `/dev/kmsg`; anything you write there ends up in the kernel buffer. So something like

```
echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger
echo "whatever you want" > /dev/kmsg
```

should do the trick... You could even add a serial message to the message in `/dev/kmsg` so you're sure you're copying the right thing afterwards, or even wrap the memory dump with two messages.

Comment: Exactly that's the question I have :) Just to understand how will echoing  to `/dev/kmsg` serializes that ?

Comment: In the best case, everything's synchronous anyway, so the dump is logged by the time the `echo m` completes; but if it isn't, I think writing to `/dev/kmsg` is synchronous, so that will wait for the memory dump to complete, log the message from the second `echo` and when *that* completes, you know everything's been logged. (Lots of hand-waving here...)

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I get it. Let me wait for some more time if some has more information on this so that I understand it completely. However in documentation it is mentioned that `handle_sysrq` runs in interrupt context but I am not sure what is difference between keyboard interrupt(MagicSysRq key) and write to proc interface in `echo m` case.